# Gradle: build task creates different versions between local machine and build host

Tags: gradle, version

I have a gradle project in GIT.

When I look `git tag`, I get a list of values ranging from v1.0.0 to v1.3.0 (including version v1.0.1 through v1.0.23)

On my local MAC, `git -q cV` returns 1.0.5-SNAPSHOT

On my build server (gitlab), the same command returns the correct value of 1.3.1-SNAPSHOT

I expect the get the same result on both machines.

Why is this happening?
How do I get them to have the same results?

Comment: What does `git -q cV` do? Are you sure that is correct, maybe you meant  to say `gradle` instead of `git`?

Comment: Your current, the command should be './gradlew -q cV'

Comment: OK. Next question; Are you sure that you've checked out the same commit on both ends? Does `git rev-parse HEAD` return the same hash?

Comment: They were different, so I did a pull on my branch, and then they were the same.

After the pull request, I am still not seeing the correct version from the -q cV command.

Comment: The pull request report no files updated

Comment: So the commits are the same... Then I guess it all depends on the implementation of the Gradle task(s) that you're running. With this little info, there's little more I can say about the possible cause of your issue. Maybe you can share your build files, so that we can see what `cV` actually does?